# angular : How to sort fetched data from api by date

Tags: angular, api, date, sorting, filter

I'm fetched movies reviews from NYT api and I want to sort result by date in descending order, How can I add this filter ?

**service**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GlobalConstants } from '../common/global-constants';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class ReviewsService {
  apiUrl = GlobalConstants.apiURL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getReviews(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(map((response:any)=>response.results))
  }
}
```

**component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReviewsService } from 'src/app/services/reviews.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reviews',
  templateUrl: './reviews.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reviews.component.css']
})
export class ReviewsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;
  constructor(private reviewsService: ReviewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReviews();
  }

  getReviews() {
    this.reviewsService.getReviews().subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.data = data;  
        console.log(typeof this.data);
        console.log(this.data);
        
              
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your service:

```
     getReviews(): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(map((response: any) 
       => response.results.sort((dataA, dataB) => {
       return ((+new Date(dataA['publication_date'])) - (+new 
       Date(dataB['publication_date'])));
     })))
    }
```

Comment: make sense, thanks Bellarej